# How can I lock a directory in C on a linux machine

Tags: linux, locking, directory, flock

Will flock or lockf work on a directory?
I there another way to lock a directory in C on a linux machine?

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by lock.

Comment: Just make the directory read-only; that seems to most closely approximate the notion of a "locked" directory.

Comment: Why do you want to lock a directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a directory for writing, so that means you can't get a write lock on it.

Even if you could, please keep in mind that `flock` and `fcntl` and other kinds of POSIX locks are advisory, so they don't actually prevent software that doesn't respect the lock from doing things.

Maybe you want to look at something like `xfs_freeze` which locks an entire filesystem. It's probably not useful for your use case though.

Comment: You don't need to open it for writing to get an exclusive lock:

$ mkdir testdir
$ strace flock testdir -c 'echo foo'
...
open("testdir", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY, 0666) = -1 EISDIR (Is a directory)
open("testdir", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY)      = 3
flock(3, LOCK_EX)                       = 0
...

Comment: I stand corrected... for `flock` style locks. For `fcntl` style locks it seems you do need write access to request a write lock.

Answer (score 1):

> *Will `flock` or `lockf` work on a directory?*

[`flock`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) - yes, [`lockf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) - no.

You can open the directory for reading and get an advisory exclusive lock using [`flock`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html):

```c
int fd = open("somedir", O_RDONLY);
if (flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) == 0) {
  // success
} else {
  // failed
}
```

But you can't open a directory for writing, which means you can't get a [`fcntl`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)-style exclusive lock on it, neither advisory nor mandatory.

---

Of course, if you actually need to *prevent shared access to a directory*, that's an entirely different question from *locking* - you can change its permissions, rename it, lock the entire filesystem, use IPC, etc.