# Lock Folder in linux

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, synchronization, gnome-terminal

I am developing a file synchronization application in linux using c++. My application should **not allow user to open a folder when it is being synced**. How can I achieve this? is there any way to use chmod to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816941/how-can-i-lock-a-directory-in-c-on-a-linux-machine

Comment: Linux doesn't have "folders". Are you using this word because it refers to something different from a directory in the filesystem?

Comment: I mean the  directory @kaz